# git push just add last commit message in server but I want all

Tags: git, git-push

I do multiple commit in my local pc then when push them to git server it just show last commit message but I want to see all of them. How can I do that?

Comment: what is 'it'? some web interface? git client?

Comment: in git server it has some interface to show commits I mean that

Comment: a web interface? which one? we cannot know if you don't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` will show you all the commit messages on your current branch.

`git log remotes/origin/master` will show you all the commit messages for your remote branch `master` on `origin`.

Comment: aha now I see commits :). I think it's problem of git server web interface that not show all commits, thanks.

Comment: @mohsenkw i don't know of any web interface for git that wouldn't show all commits (even though there are quite many)